# Netflix: Fetching new remote data when it becomes readily available

Tags: php, fetch, netflix

I hope this is an appropriate question: I'm using the Netflix API and I'm wondering what the best way one would be able to automatically receive new data when presented (in this case, recently watched films when a Netflix user finishes watching one) The only way I can think of is spamming requests in intervals to query their feed. And would PHP be my best bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, Netflix doesn't provide any push notifications through their API. You'll have to poll their feed periodically, but not too often: your consumer key is limited to a certain number of requests per second and requests per day.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, to know whether PHP would be the right choice. OAuth libraries are available for pretty much every major language, so it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Do you know what the best language would be to poll the server's in, say, 3 hour intervals? PHP is my only back-end language handy with and suppose using cron to run a script would work. What's your take?

Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I think it's really just personal preference. Personally, I'd probably use cron to call a perl script; I think there's already a Netflix perl module in CPAN. If you're more comfortable with PHP there's no reason not to use that.